# foreach array doesn't work outside the loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to get the values of an array outside the foreach loop but it's giving me only one value not all three; the code is like this :

```
$user_id_worker = array();
    foreach ($query_result_worker as $row){
    $user_id_worker= $row['user_id'];
    var_dump($user_id_worker);
}

    var_dump($user_id_worker);
```

the first var dump gives me:

```
string '12747' (length=5)
string '12596' (length=5)
string '12759' (length=5)
```

the second one ( outside  the loop ) gives me :

```
string '12759' (length=5)
```

any ideas? thanks!

Comment: $user_id_worker is not an array, everytime it replaces its value while iterating through loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're replacing its value instead of adding a value to the array you created.

So the $user_id_worker variable holds only one value. Outside the loop, it's the last one you put inside (last iteration of the loop).

If you want to add the item to the array inside the loop, do this :

```
$user_id_worker[]= $row['user_id'];
```

Comment: quick question, if i have a function after this array and i want to use the array in it, `show_assigned_tasks_workers($user_id_worker[]);` this just won't work, how can i do it other way ? thanks!

Comment: If you want to pass the array to a function, just do `show_assigned_tasks_workers($user_id_worker);`.

Comment: it just won't work, the function do a select too, and don't know how the array will be in that function, it will work i think only if the data are like this: `string '12747' (length=5)
string '12596' (length=5)
string '12759' (length=5)` like strings ...

Comment: @Jimmy if you want to run `show_assigned_tasks_workers` for each worker you'll need to do a for each loop again, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're not treating it as an array, you just have a variable that you update.

The problem is this line `$user_id_worker = $row['user_id'];`  here you are **setting the value** of `$user_id_worker` to the row, then on the next loop you set it again to a different value. You are not treating the variable as an array.

To add to the **array** instead of replacing the old value you have to use the array shorthand or array push, see below.

Example using array shorthand:

```
$user_id_worker = array();
    foreach ($query_result_worker as $row){
    $user_id_worker[] = $row['user_id'];
}

var_dump($user_id_worker);
```

Or using [array push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

```
foreach ($query_result_worker as $row){
    array_push($user_id_worker, $row['user_id']);
}

var_dump($user_id_worker);
```

---

Additional question from Jimmy

> quick question, if i have a function after this array and i want to use the array in it, show_assigned_tasks_workers($user_id_worker[]); this just won't work, how can i do it other way ? thanks! – Jimmy 17 mins ago
>
> it just won't work, the function do a select too, and don't know how the array will be in that function, it will work i think only if the data are like this: string '12747' (length=5) string '12596' (length=5) string '12759' (length=5) like strings ... – Jimmy 14 mins ago

You probably need to do a for each loop around the function you are calling (one for each worker).

Do something like:

```
foreach ($user_id_worker as &$workerId) {
  show_assigned_tasks_workers($workerId);
}
```

Which runs that function once for each of the users.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this won't work too because my function create a table with info and your updated answer makes the function creates 3 tables foreach id, i want one table with all ids in it. do you understand me :) ?

Comment: Please accept an answer and post this as a new question, we'll need to see the code of this function.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the values like: `$user_id_worker[] = "something"`

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a new value to `$user_id_worker` in each loop pass.

If you want all value as an array, you have to add the values to that array:

```
$user_id_worker[] = $row['user_id'];
// or:
array_push( $user_id_worker, $row['user_id'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your program this way:

```
$user_id_worker = array();
    foreach ($query_result_worker as $row){
    $user_id_worker[] = $row['user_id'];
    var_dump($user_id_worker);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct your code

```
$user_id_worker = array();
    foreach ($query_result_worker as $row){
    $user_id_worker[]=$row['user_id']; //Should give [] as ur appending to array
    var_dump($user_id_worker);
}

    var_dump($user_id_worker);
```